# Django transaction.commit_on_success rolling back even though exception is not raised

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions, rollback

I have a scenario where a `transaction.commit_on_success()` is being rolled back after the code block finishes execution without raising error.

The `DataBaseError` is being caught and retried explicitly within that transaction.

If there are 10 requests coming in simultaneously, for the one's where the retry executes, rollback happens for those objects even though a voucher is served in the first retry.

Assuming I have `brand`, `amount` and `currency` already, below is my code base

```py
def get_coupon_code(brand, currency, amount, retry=4)
    try:
        qs = VoucherCode.select_for_update().filter(
            brand=brand, currency=currency, amount=amount
        ).values('id', 'voucher_code').order_by('id')[:1]
        try:
            return qs[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
    except DatabaseError as err:
        if retry and hasattr(err, 'args') and err.args[0] == 1213:
            retry -= 1
            time.sleep(4)
            return self.get_coupon_code(
                brand=brand, currency=currency, amount=amount, retry=retry)
        else:
            raise err


try:
    with transaction.commit_on_success():
        object = Coupon.objects.create(brand=brand)
        voucher_code = get_coupon_code(brand, currency, amount)
        code = voucher_code.get('voucher_code')
        object.voucher_code = code
        try:
            voucher_obj = VoucherCode.objects.get(voucher_code=code)
            voucher_obj.delete()
        except VoucherCode.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return object
except Exception as error:
    raise MyCustomException()
```

Comment: See [Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic). Also, are you aware that `commit_on_success()` is an outdated API, undocumented as of Django 1.8?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, yes `commit_on_success()` is outdated. But on the current version thats the only choice I have. Anyhow, we sorted out a patch to get past this issue. Thanks for the suggestion.